# How to manually set the order of articles in Drupal 8 front page

Tags: sorting, drupal-8, article, frontpage

I need to know of a way to manually order the articles displayed in the Drupal 8 front page by displaying a title in-between each piece.
For example,

Title A
Article 2
Article 5
Article 3

Title B
Article 1
Article 7

I've tried configuring the front page view and looked into the Drupal 8 article and basic page settings but couldn't determine an effective way by which the above could be achieved. If you anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight) module lets you set a weight for each node, with the lower weighted nodes floating to the tops of lists and heavier will sink.